# Check to see if URL exists and is linked to audio file

Tags: javascript

I've written a test to validate that an audio (MP3, WAV) is in the correct URL format.

Now I want to check two things:

1. that the URL exists
2. make a head request to make sure that the URL is linking to an audio file

How do I do that? I've yet to find any good JavaScript examples on making head requests.

```js
// The test being performed    

if (result.onClose === true) {
  if(UtilService.isValidUrl(result.url) && UtilService.isValidAudioUrl(result.url)) {
    console.log('url is valid')
  }
}

// In UtilService

static isValidUrl(urlToCheck: string) {
  let url;
  try {
    url = new URL(urlToCheck);
  } catch (_) {
    return false;
  }
  return url.protocol === 'http:' || url.protocol === 'https:';
}

// Unsure how to perform the check here

static isValidAudioUrl(urlToCheck: string) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("HEAD", urlToCheck);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }};
  xhr.send();

  // I'd like it to return a boolean value of true or false in isValidAudioUrl if the response header indicates the media type of the URL is audio and exists

  return false;
}
```

Comment: How is this failing? Can you state the exact blocker?

Comment: I'd like it to return a boolean value of true or false in `isValidAudioUrl` if the response header indicates the media type of the URL is audio and exists.

Comment: I understand your task. I'm wondering about the exact blocker that you have, that prompted you to ask this question. Your snippet does not run, hence, before I start looking into your problem I need to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Oh sorry for not explaining. My current blocker is not being able to figure out how to do perform this check given a valid and invalid audio url. Apologies for the snippet not working.

Comment: No worries, I'm also a highly rated user who occasionally asks a question and is downvoted by some people. I think your question is valid, I just have some points of clarifications. So, is the invalid audio URL a valid URL not pointing to an audio or a totally invalid URL? Btw, I know no more about this issue than you, but let's try to figure it out.

Comment: Ah let me clarify, for example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/27/Afternoon_at_Tennfjorden%2C_Raftsundet%2C_Hinn%C3%B8ya%2C_Norway%2C_2015_September_%2802%29.jpg/1280px-Afternoon_at_Tennfjorden%2C_Raftsundet%2C_Hinn%C3%B8ya%2C_Norway%2C_2015_September_%2802%29.jpg is not a valid audio URL

Comment: Whereas, https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3 would be a n example of a good audio URL

Comment: I perform the validation for if the URL is correct in `isValidUrl`

Comment: I see, thanks. Can you put sample correct and incorrect header responses into your question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your audio URL validation function may look like this.
The idea is to check the `Content-type` response header. For audio files it usually starts with *audio* (e.g. *audio/mpeg*)

```
function isValidAudioUrl(urlToCheck) {
  return fetch(urlToCheck, { method: 'HEAD', mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then(res => res.ok && res.headers.get('content-type').startsWith('audio'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));
}

// In your code
console.log('validating');

isValidAudioUrl('https://<YOUR_URL>.mp3')
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I get the following error message `Access to fetch at 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: You could try no-cors mode (updated the answer)